# Firebase works on custom web app but not on wordpress : Uncaught ReferenceError: firebase is not defined

Tags: wordpress, firebase

I am trying to add my firebase project to my wordpress website (following the official documentation) but got Uncaught ReferenceError: firebase is not defined

I tried adding firebase, the same way, to a custom web app and it worked.

I added the code snippet provided by Firebase, in the body tag (as recommended by Google). You can check the code on the website : https://testing.myfprod.fr

It worked instantly on my custom web project but I am still getting the error Uncaught ReferenceError: firebase is not defined on wordpress.

Unfortunately I did not find an answer, in a previously asked question, that could solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that LSCache was configured to defer js script. I disabled this option and it now works.

Comment: FYI, there's a JS Deferred Excludes function inside the lscache plugin.